# import price google docs one cell

Tags: google-docs

I want to import the price from this website into my google docs file

https://www.afuture.nl/product/5517274/intel-core-i77700k-boxed

The price of writing this question is 382,30

Right now I have this line of code:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.afuture.nl/product/5517274/intel-core-i77700k-boxed";"//div[@class='large-price lowered']")
```

But the € is in a different cell than the price

I dont need the € icon, I only want the price in one cell.

hope someone can help

Answer (score 0):

There probably is an easier way but this joins the two columns then removes the € symbol:

```
=Regexreplace(Concatenate(IMPORTXML("https://www.afuture.nl/product/5517274/intel-core-i77700k-boxed","//div[@class='large-price lowered']")), "€ ", "")
```